# Datagridview not displaying data until I select a cell or use the scroll wheel over it

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

I am using Visual Studio 2019 and writing in vb.net. The datagridview displays the columns but no row information until I scroll over them.

```
    DefineTrackerDataTable()
    LoadDtbTracker()
    Me.dgvTracker.DataSource = dtbTracker
```

I have searched but found nothing relevant. Any clues?

Comment: Try on another machine? This seems more like a graphics card driver bug or something

Comment: I see similar behaviour on my machine but I'm not sure what the cause is. I've tried calling `Refresh` on the `Shown` event but that didn't work. It seems to right itself as soon as focus changes so I tried clearing and resetting the `ActiveControl` property but that didn't work. It occurs in a Debug build, whether run in the debugger or directly. The good news is that it doesn't occur in a Release build, so I just ignore it.

Comment: Thank you @jmcilhinney for your feedback. I decided for what I am doing a datatable works fine. I don't even need to fool with the view right now.